# Clickable toggle solution in ionic, or a better UI element

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, ionic-framework

I have some hierarchical category. E.g:

- Adult (on/off)
- Gambling (on/off)
- Social (on/off)

  - Facebook (on/off)
  - Instagram (on/off)
  - Kik (on/off)

For the categories with no sub-categories, I'd like to have a simple toggle. However, for the sub-categories, i'd like to be able to EITHER, toggle the whole category on/off, or click on it and toggle individual sites on and off.

I have a codepen here with how it could look visually: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOZjmx

JS

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [
    { 
      id: 0,
      drillDown: true
    },
    { 
      id: 1,
      drillDown: false },
    { 
      id: 2,
      drillDown: false },
  ];
});
```

HTML

```
     <ion-list>
        <ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in items">
          Item {{ item.id }}
          <i ng-hide="{{!item.drillDown}}" class="ion-chevron-right"></i>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Problem is, as soon as you make something an ion-toggle, only the toggle glyph becomes clickable. So, I'd be interested in a solution on how to make the whole row clickable (so I can navigate to a child screen) OR a different UI element to achieve the same.

Comment: So you essentially need click callback for the ion-item ?? BTW, you have a mistake in your HTML. ion-item is not starting, but it is being ended.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you're trying to wire up an event handler to the click of both of your toggle and ion-item. This can be easily done by setting up ng-clicks on both the controls. However, the pain in the head is event bubbling.

Since the ion-toggle is essentially inside your ion-item, clicking on ion-toggle will invoke ng-click of toggle as well as item. In order to prevent it, you must stop event propagation.

[image]

Now, the updated HTML will look like :

```
<ion-content>

    <!-- The list directive is great, but be sure to also checkout the collection repeat directive when scrolling through large lists -->

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="callClick()">
            <ion-toggle ng-model="item.drillDown" ng-click="toggleClick($event)">
                Item {{ item.id }}
                <i ng-hide="{{!item.drillDown}}" class="ion-chevron-right"></i>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And in the JS Code :

```
$scope.toggleClick = function($event) {
    alert("toggle click");
    $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
};

$scope.callClick = function() {
    alert("i was clicked");
};
```